# Can the action attribute on a form element be empty?

Tags: php, html, forms

As of HTML5, the widely used and recommended `action=""` is invalid HTML.

From the specs:

> The action and formaction content attributes, if specified, must have
>   a value that is a valid URL.

So what is the correct way to have the `action` attribute point to the current page?

I am currently using

```
action="<php htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); ?>"
```

Comment: As far as I can see it's valid ... http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090825/forms.html#attr-fs-action

Comment: where did you see it's invalid anyway?

Comment: Do you mean that the attribute being empty is invalid?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Yes. Atleast that's what the W3 Validator says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that the `action=` attribute may not be empty, as an empty string is not a valid URL. However, it is valid to simply leave it out, and let the browser figure it out.

The browser will assume the current page.

Comment: w3Schools says it's "no longer necessary": http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_form_action.asp Not sure how accurate that is.

Comment: @Mansfield: w3schools is a wrong and misleading site. You shouldn't use it as reference for any sort of language. For PHP, there's the [PHP Manual](http://php.net), for JavaScript, there's [Mozilla Developer Network (or MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/). See http://w3fools.com to further understand why you should never use w3schools.

Comment: Interesting. I never took it as an official source, but I never knew any of that. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

You can set value to '.' or do not set action attribute at all.

```
<form method="post">
or
<form method="post" action=".">
```

(I was surprise but it is really invalid to leave it blank, at least validator.w3.org is returning error).

Answer (score 0):

No, in HTML5, the [`action` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/attributes-common-to-form-controls.html#attr-fs-action) may be omitted, and it defaults to the emoty string, which means a reference to the current document.