# PHP array diplaying as plain text in HTML page

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have PHP and HTML files on my IIS site and am trying to get the output of a form shown on the same page.  The issue I am running into is when I load the HTML page I am seeing the array information show as plain text on that page.  I have form action = "" defined.  Alternatively, when I have form action = "file.php" defined, I get the desired results, but on a new page.  I took a look at the the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22260476/php-showing-up-as-plain-text) but didn't seem to provide what I am looking for.  I tried adding the  tags on each line, which helped a bit but am still seeing the array as plain text.  Here is what I have:

```
<form action="" method = "POST">
MAC Address of phone: <input type="text" name="phonemac"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Check Phone Status">
</form>

<?php

$host = "server.com";
$username = "*****";
$password = "*****";

$context = 
stream_context_create(array('ssl'=>array('allow_self_signed'=>true)));

$client = new SoapClient("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PhoneSetup\AXLAPI.wsdl",
array('trace'=>true,
'exceptions'=>true,
'location'=>"https://".$host.":8443/axl",
'login'=>$username,
'password'=>$password,
'stream_context'=>$context

));

$response = $client->getPhone(array("name"=>"$_POST[phonemac]"));
$array = json_decode(json_encode($response), true);

echo $array['return']['phone']['description'];echo '<br><br>';
echo $array['return']['phone']['name']; echo;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680007/can-the-action-attribute-on-a-form-element-be-empty

Answer (score 0):

This

```
$myArray = json_decode($data, true);
echo $myArray[0]['id']; // Fetches the first ID
echo $myArray[0]['c_name']; // Fetches the first c_name
// ...
```

I will write a example with your code

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($response), true);

echo $array[0]['phone']
echo $array[0]['description'];
echo '</br></br>';
echo $array[0]['phone'];
echo $array[0]['name'];
```

your code would be like

```
<form action="" method = "POST">
MAC Address of phone: <input type="text" name="phonemac"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Check Phone Status">
</form>

<?php

$host = "server.com";
$username = "*****";
$password = "*****";

$context = 
stream_context_create(array('ssl'=>array('allow_self_signed'=>true)));

$client = new SoapClient("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PhoneSetup\AXLAPI.wsdl",
array('trace'=>true,
'exceptions'=>true,
'location'=>"https://".$host.":8443/axl",
'login'=>$username,
'password'=>$password,
'stream_context'=>$context

));

$response = $client->getPhone(array("name"=>"$_POST[phonemac]"));
$array = json_decode(json_encode($response), true);


    echo $array[0]['phone']
    echo $array[0]['description'];
    echo '</br></br>';
    echo $array[0]['phone'];
    echo $array[0]['name']; 
    ?>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, however the issue begins with the array entry starting with the `array('allow_self_signed'=>true` string in the `$context` variable.  Sorry for not clarifying.  Running what you proposed yields the same result.

Comment: Anyone?  I updated the form action statement to align with HTML5 standards.